# Divide Serializer Django rest framework

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have a Serializer receiving:

```
{
    "suggestions": [
      {
       "description": "Portugal - Porto",       
       "integration_data": {
        .......
         }
      },
     {
      "description": "Portugal - Porto",
      "another_data":{
       .......
      }
     }]
}
```

How can I make my Serializer do something like:
if `integration_data` is not Null go to function X where I will work with all logic of the serializer
if `another_data` is not Null go to function Y where I will work with all logic of the serializer.

At the moment my serializer is written as:

```
class SuggestionSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    integration_data = serializers.DictField(write_only=True, allow_null=True, required=False)
    sponsor_data = serializers.DictField(write_only=True, allow_null=True, required=False)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to use a [serializer method field](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield).   Something like

```
class SuggestionSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    integration_data = = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    ...
    def get_integration_data(self, obj):
        # Insert logic for generating value of this field here
        ...
        return value
```

This allows you to arbitrarily generate the value of the field based on logic rather than data.

Comment: SerializerMethodFields are read only and I believe the author appears to desire writeable fields.

Comment: yes they are read only -- do you think that the author of the question wants to process the data with a function before saving it...? Not entirely sure what the question is.

Comment: I think so yes, but I do not think they do not correspond to model fields. Perhaps just a custom create...

Comment: Hi, I resolved that creating 2 different serializers